Simulate high watermark memory limit exceeded error on simulator
When running my Flutter app through Xcode on a real iPhone 12 my app crashes because of this error:
io.flutter.1.profiler (13): EXC_RESOURCE (RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY: high watermark memory limit exceeded) (limit=2098 MB)

However, on the iPhone 12 simulator I don't get this error under the same scenario or even if further memory stress the app. How can I simulate this error on the simulator? Debug -> Simulate Memory Warning doesn't do anything.
Both the device and simulator are running iOS 17.5.

"Debug -> Simulate Memory Warning doesn't do anything" Yes, it does. But it doesn't run you out of memory. It just sends the warning. If you have not registered to receive the UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, then nothing will seem to happen. In any case you are not going to get the same crash on the simulator; you must debug this on the phone. Memory management on the simulator is nothing like memory management on a device. Use Instruments to get a handle on what's happening.

When debugging through VS Code on real device, I just get a crash without any message. Has the 2098 MB limit been increased on newer devices?

Sorry, for the Flutter world I'm no help. :(

Would you know if iOS implements a 2098 MB memory limit?

I don't think so. I thought the system just makes a judgment based on how much memory there is.

On a 6th gen iPad, the limit is 1450 MB.
